# Parse string with a 5-digit year to POSIXct

Tags: r, posixct, posixlt

I want to parse a character with a 5-digit (or more) year, e.g. `10000-01-01  01:00:00` to class `POSIXct`.

A 4-digit year is of course no problem. For example,

```
as.POSIXct("1000-01-01  01:00:00")
```

But with a 5-digit year, e.g. 10000, `as.POSIXct` errors:

```
as.POSIXct("10000-01-01  01:00:00") 
# Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
#      character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
```

I wonder is there a way to handle year with more than 4 digits in R?

Comment: `as.POSIXct()` appears to be limited to 4 digit years.  (But I'd be happy to be proved wrong.)  However, `x <-Sys.time(); lubridate::year(x) <- 10000; x` gives me (right now!) `[1] "10000-08-02 22:27:40 BST"`, so maybe you need to take an indirect approach to creating your datetime objects.

Comment: `lubridate::make_datetime()` seems be a route to creating your date time objects, once you've broken the strings down to their component parts and converted to numeric.  As does `base::ISOdatetime()`.

Comment: `ISOdatetime` doesn't seem to like years beyond 10000 either - `ISOdatetime(year=10000, month=1, day=1, hour=1, min=0, sec=0)` gives `NA` while using `year=9999` works fine. Which is not surprising as it uses `as.POSIXct` inside the function.

Comment: Just a ref to the docs, from `?strptime`: "`%Y`: ... For input, only years `0:9999` are accepted"

Comment: @thelatemail.  OK.  I didn't check `ISOdatetime()`.  But `lubridate::make_datetime()` appears to be behave correctly.

Comment: I'm curious about the use case for dates beyond year 10000 - is this for astronomy? I'd think for most use cases the year (or year+decimals) would suffice and be easier to work with.

Comment: Hi Jon, I am finding adjacent time points (YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS) whose interval is greater than 12 hours, for each of ~20k patients. If I find them for each patient (even with `by()` or parallel processing), the calculation time is really long. The trick is to assign each patient a specific year, then finding adjacent time points with >12 hour interval is fast because I only work on one vector.

Comment: @WCMC I get a nagging feeling of an XY problem. Your "trick" seems a bit convoluted. I bet you could speed up your computations by group considerably by switching from `base::by` to `data.table`. Just my 2c. Anyway: good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no problem handling years with 5 digits, it's the `as.POSIXct.character` function that is the problem here, since it uses `strptime`, which can only handle years 0-9999.

The following code produces a POSIXct object of the correct date/time:

```r
structure(253402304400, class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))
#> [1] "10000-01-01 01:00:00 GMT"
```

If you use `POSIXlt` to construct the date-times, you can assign the year part numerically, then convert to POSIXct, which allows the following function to be defined. It will do the same as `as.POSIXct` but can handle large years:

```r
as.bigPOSIX <- function(x) {
  y <- as.POSIXlt(sub("^\\d+", "2000", x))
  y$year <- sapply(strsplit(x, "-"), function(a) as.numeric(a[1])) - 1900
  as.POSIXct(y)
}
```

For example:

```r
as.bigPOSIX(c("10000-01-01 01:00:00", "23456-03-09 12:04:01", 
               "2022-07-05 23:59:59"))
#> [1] "10000-01-01 01:00:00 GMT" "23456-03-09 12:04:01 GMT" 
#> [3] "2022-07-05 23:59:59 GMT"
```

Comment: Great! In the second line of your function, perhaps a `sub` there as well: `as.numeric(sub("-.*", "", x)) - 1900`?